# Get Jboss EAP 7.4 fix list in json format

Tags: jboss7.x

is there any way to get a list of jboss EAP fix list in json format ? or at least to get the latest fix pack - example 7.4.1.2 or so on..
I am trying to write a script to get regularly the latest fix version and i form on which servers it should be installed.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is also interested.. there is another way.
This is the PHP code:

```
//$ver="7.4"; example..
    $arrver=array("7.4"=>0,"7.3"=>1,"7.2"=>2,"7.1"=>3,"7.0"=>4);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $data="";
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $html=file_get_contents("https://access.redhat.com/articles/2332721");
    $html=preg_replace('%<sup.*?</sup>%i', '', $html);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
    $rows = $tables->item($arrver[$ver])->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
    $i=0;
    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
     $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
     if (DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $cols->item(1)->nodeValue) !== false) {
      $i++;
       if($i==1){ $data=$ver.".".str_replace(array("Update ","\n","\t"," "),"",$cols->item(0)->nodeValue);}
       }
    }
```